# C# SoundPlayer static after WAV plays

Tags: c#, .net, audio, wav, soundplayer

I'm using this code to play a WAV file from a resource, and the audio plays correctly, but then I get a short blast of static after it plays (about 1/2 second):

```
//System.Media.SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
SoundPlayer sndPlayer = new SoundPlayer();
sndPlayer.Stream = Resources.Notify;
sndPlayer.Play();
```

If I uncomment the `System.Media.SystemSounds.Beep.Play()` line above, then the beep and the Notify sound from my resources both play correctly, and no static.  I've tried a few different variations of the above code, and always getting the static.  I tried making all of the variables static, incase there was something related to early garbage collection, but that didn't help.

The WAV file is just one I copied from `c:\WINDOWS\Media\ding.wav` (on Windows XP) and it plays fine in Windows Media Player.  Also, if I use new `SoundPlayer("c:\WINDOWS\Media\ding.wav")`, it plays correctly from the file.

I imagine it has something to do with the `UnmanagedMemoryStream` that `Resources.Notify` is, and maybe I need to load it in to a managed stream first?  I know I've had issues with PNG files if I don't use `new Bitmap(Resource.MyPNG)` and try to use `Resource.MyPNG` directly instead, so maybe something similar with WAV resources?

**Update :** I originally thought it was happening everytime the sound played, but now it appears it only happens the very first time I play the sound in my app.  So maybe some initialization needs to be done?

I also tried this, same issue:

```
SoundPlayer sndPlayer = new SoundPlayer(Resources.Notify);
sndPlayer.Play();
```

Comment: Are you able to quickly test if the same problem occurs on another PC? rule out the sound card...

Comment: Funny you ask, I'm home now and it isn't happening on my home PC.  I suspect it could be an issue with that PC, or maybe even related to running under the VS debugger.  I'll test on several PCs tomorrow, if only an issue on the one, I guess it might be a non-issue.

Comment: It is odd that it plays fine from file though (passing SoundPlayer the file name), but that's how bugs sometimes work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was just an issue on one PC.  Never figured it out, and other apps don't appear to have this issue, but not worth my time if only on 1 PC (out of maybe 15 tested) so far.  Will report a better answer if I ever get one.

Answer (score 0):

This is the internal implementation that MS use *My.Audio.Play()*, see how they instantiate the SoundPlayer class, they take advantage of the overloaded constructor that **takes a filePath** as shown below **or a stream**:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer.aspx

```
public void Play(string location, AudioPlayMode playMode)
{
    this.ValidateAudioPlayModeEnum(playMode, "playMode");
    SoundPlayer sound = new SoundPlayer(this.ValidateFilename(location));
    this.Play(sound, playMode);
}
```

Can you try passing in a stream when instantiating the SoundPlayer?

Comment: I did try this, I'll edit my post to show the method I tried.